# Setting placement labels on "Offset From Point" with OffsetX,Y parameters in PyQGIS?

Tags: labeling, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to set properties of QgsVectorLayer using QGIS 3. I want to put labels with "Offset from point" and define "Offset X" and Offset Y". I saw on the documentary that there is a class "setQuadrantPosition" from QgsPalLayerSettings but i don't know how to use it. Here is my code :

`layer=iface.activeLayer()
layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
layer_settings.fieldName = "Name"
layer_settings.enabled = True
layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
layer_settings.setQuadrantPosition(5)
layer.triggerRepaint()
qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())`

Here is a picture of what i want to set up :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to set up your label placement properties, see comments:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
layer_settings.fieldName = "Name"

# Placement: Cartographic = 6; Around point = 0; Offset from point = 1
layer_settings.placement = 1
# Quadrant position: QuadrantAboveLeft = 0; QuadrantAbove = 1,...
layer_settings.quadOffset = 5
# Offset X
layer_settings.xOffset = 3.0
# Offset Y
layer_settings.yOffset = 3.0

layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Really helpfull for me, thanks again !

Comment: @ValentinL. - Most welcome! Glad it helped again :)