# QGIS Set Label Placement in Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm writing a plugin that extracts some data from a Postgres database, saves a point shapefile of the data and displays it in QGIS. As part of that process, I want to generate a QML style file.

I have this basically working - with the exception of the label placement. I want the label placed NE (above and right) of the point, offset X=1, Y=0.

I have the following code. It all works - but the label is placed 'Around point' rather than offset up and to the right.

```
    #Add labels.
    layer_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    layer_settings.fieldName = "gr"
    layer_settings.isExpression = True

    layer_settings.OffsetType = QgsPalLayerSettings.FromPoint
    layer_settings.OffsetQuad = 'NE'
    layer_settings.OffsetXY = '1,0'
    layer_settings.OffsetUnits = QgsUnitTypes.RenderUnit.RenderMillimeters
    layer_settings.enabled = True

    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial Black", 6))
    text_format.setSize(6)
    layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

    labeling = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    layer.setLabeling(labeling)
    layer.triggerRepaint()

    # Save the style file for future use in QGIS.
    outputFile = os.path.join(self.SearchOutputFolder, searchCategoryFileName) + '.qml'
    layer.saveNamedStyle(outputFile)
```

I've had to guess how to use OffsetQuad and OffsetXY. I just can't seem to find any documentation on how to call/set them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a duplicate of this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325137/setting-placement-labels-on-offset-from-point-with-offsetx-y-parameters-in-pyq) but you could use the following to set up your label placements:

```
# Placement: Cartographic = 6; Around point = 0; Offset from point = 1
layer_settings.placement = 1
# Quadrant position: QuadrantAboveLeft = 0; QuadrantAbove = 1,...
layer_settings.quadOffset = 2
# Offset X
layer_settings.xOffset = 1.0
# Offset Y
layer_settings.yOffset = 0.0
```

---

So your code could look like:

```
#Add labels.
layer_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
layer_settings.fieldName = "gr"
layer_settings.isExpression = True

layer_settings.placement = 1
layer_settings.quadOffset = 2
layer_settings.xOffset = 1.0
layer_settings.yOffset = 0.0
layer_settings.enabled = True

text_format = QgsTextFormat()
text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial Black", 6))
text_format.setSize(6)
layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

labeling = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(labeling)
layer.triggerRepaint()

# Save the style file for future use in QGIS.
outputFile = os.path.join(self.SearchOutputFolder, searchCategoryFileName) + '.qml'
layer.saveNamedStyle(outputFile)
```

Comment: Thanks @Joseph - that worked great. Where can i find the documentation for this?

Comment: @SteveGoddard - Most welcome, glad it helped! You can find some information in the class api for [QgsPalLayerSettings](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html). You can find some examples [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/24e56a810cba9d531776af133c4f60158d9a4429/tests/src/python/test_qgspallabeling_tests.py).

Comment: Great work @Joseph, really appreciate the **layer_settings.placement = 1** comments