# Setting Label placement for centroids in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, centroids

Using 3.10.1-A Coruña on Windows 10

I want to adjust my label placement options in a Python script.

I've had a look at the [QgsPalLayerSettings Class Reference](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html) and similar questions at:

- [QGIS Set Label Placement in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326166) ; and
- [Setting placement labels on "Offset From Point" with OffsetX,Y parameters in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325137)

but can't find where I can set the Centroid options in PyQGIS like I can in my UI shown in the pic below.

[image]

My UI looks very different to the one in the similar question at [Setting placement labels on "Offset From Point" with OffsetX,Y parameters in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325137)

I'm guessing it will be in the settings class. I have added settings.placement = 0 as I understand that is Around, but not sure how to set placement to Centroid:Whole Polygon and Force visible point inside polygon with PyQGIS

```
settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
settings.fieldName = 'POA_CODE16'
settings.placement = 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `QgsPalLayerSettings` class has the boolean attributes: `centroidInside` and `centroidWhole`.

[See docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#a670b0f842cbe0a6170a996f2a2a6ccf9)

So, you could add the following lines:

```
settings.centroidWhole = True
settings.centroidInside = True
```

This will calculate the centroid from the whole polygon and force the centroid positioned labels inside their corresponding polygon features.